# Time Conversion using Javascript function

Tags: javascript, time, timestamp, datetime-conversion

I have requirement to convert the timestamp from

```
05-FEB-19 01.33.11.000000 AM
//to
2019-02-05T01:33:11+00:00
```

in javascript as a function.

I will be passing a input to this `function` i.e., `05-FEB-19 01.33.11.000000 AM` and it should give me the output as

`2019-02-05T01:33:11+00:00`

Can anyone help with this

Comment: considering '05-FEB-19 01.33.11.000000' is an invalid date, you're first going to need to convert that into a valid date format. where is that coming from? Have you tried any libs like moment.js?

Comment: You might want to use http://momentjs.com

Comment: Can you provide more date examples? What is `.000000`

Comment: This is what i was using in DB to convert to the required format.select TO_CHAR(FROM_TZ(TO_TIMESTAMP('05-FEB-19 01.33.11.000000 AM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF AM'),'UTC'),'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSTZH:TZM') from du

Comment: @StevenStark I am using the SQL Query as , select TO_CHAR(FROM_TZ(TO_TIMESTAMP('05-FEB-19 01.33.11.000000 AM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF AM'),'UTC'),'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSTZH:TZM') from dual which will provide the output. How to do the same in Javascript

Comment: That's not a supported date format in JS, why are you returning a custom date format instead of using standards?

Comment: @StevenStark That is coming from other system. Hence we need to transform and send it to the target